# Request error 401 No authentication token, authorization denied. Why am i getting this error and how to bypass this

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, frontend

As soon as the page loads I get the above error where do I get the authentication token.

I was expecting that after the required installation and downgraded to node v 16 it would work normally.
The react page loads and I immediately see this error.
What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

In your code maybe you are calling some API that requires an authentication header like, `"Authorization": "Bearer your_token"`.

Generally, a 401 error means unauthorized access. so please check your API calling code and make sure you are passing an Authorization token to the API.

Hope this helps, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use browser inspector --> Go to network tab and check which specific API call is returning 401 response and check that specific part of the code

[image]